# html email margin of photos outlook2013

Tags: html, css, html-email, outlook-2013

I'm making html email. I have made this in gmail:

[image]

but in outlook it looks like this:
[image]

how can i solve this problem?

```
<img src="http://leavingstone.me/dev/Images_For/MoneyMan/FB.png" align="left" style="width: 29px; height: 29px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; margin: 2px;display: block;line-height: 100%;">
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/thts599h/)

Comment: u mean margin on images is not shown in outlook?

Comment: @Umair yes i mean that

Comment: use padding in stead of margin

Comment: @user25312 same result. after that I have used both margin and padding but same result..

Comment: Why not make them as PNG and have a border radius and some empty space in that PNG .... rather than applying diff styles to handle different email clients

Answer (score 2):

Check if `border-radius` is supported in email: [Link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).
Better use images for that.
Also, wendor prefixes are valid only if email is viewed via browser.

Try changing `margin` with padding:

```css
.soc {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: blue;
}
.twitter {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.google-plus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="facebook soc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="twitter soc"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="google-plus soc"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have deleted border-radius but same result for outlook

Comment: @George what outlook version? Does it looks the same on other email clients?

Comment: @George have you seen this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3921/outlook.com-drops-margin-and-float-support-entirely ?

Comment: It's outlook 2013. it looks same in outlook 2007. but in gmail it's everything is ok

Comment: same result about !important. on margin and padding too

Comment: I have tried padding: 2px !important; but outlook sucks!!

Comment: Why not make them as PNG and have a border radius and some empty space in that PNG .... rather than applying diff styles to handle different email clients

Comment: @George Good to hear that you agree to my opinion :D